# Only the last addEventListener responds to click events in loop

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to set addEventListener for elements belonging to a certain class, only the last element the listener was assigned to responds to click events. I'm pretty sure the element `childNode` which I attempt to assign the listener to is unique. So I'm not sure what could be causing the issue. I would really appreciate any help.

Javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
  slideContainers = document.getElementsByClassName("slideContainer");
  for (i=0;i<slideContainers.length;i++){
    newSlideshow = new slideshow();
    for (c=0;c<slideContainers[i].childNodes.length;c++){
      childNode = slideContainers[i].childNodes[c];
      if (childNode.className=="slideDesc"){
          for (d=0;d<childNode.childNodes.length;d++){ 
            if (childNode.childNodes[d].className=="myDesc fade"){
              newSlideshow.slideDescArr.push(childNode.childNodes[d]);              
            }
          }
      }
      if (childNode.className=="slideImg"){
          for (d=0;d<childNode.childNodes.length;d++){ 
            if (childNode.childNodes[d].className=="mySlides fade"){
              newSlideshow.slideImgArr.push(childNode.childNodes[d]);
            }
          }        
      }
      if (childNode.className=="numbertext"){
        newSlideshow.slideNumArr.push(childNode);
      }
      if (childNode.className=="prev"){ //Help! Only the last childNode responds to click event
        childNode.addEventListener("click", function(){ plusSlides(newSlideshow, -1); });           
      }
      if (childNode.className=="next"){ //Help! Only the last childNode responds to click event
        childNode.addEventListener("click", function(){ plusSlides(newSlideshow, 1); });
      }
    }
    showSlides(newSlideshow, newSlideshow.slideIndex);
  }
} //wait for all resources to load
```

HTML

```
<div class="projectname">
<%= image_tag "gamepad.png", :class=>"icon_image"%>

<div class="slideContainer">

  <div class="slideDesc">
    <p class = "myDesc fade">
      Farm Wars: Zombie Survival is a RPG as a duck farmer who must survive in a zombie-infested desert with a handful of tools and weapons. This Unity game is compatible with Android phones.
    </p>

    <p class = "myDesc fade">
      I built this stock market educational game to encourage users to adopt a wiser approach toward investing. I scraped info of public companies to quiz users who could use their earnings to build their portfolio. I used Sqlite3 to store user progress and MediaWiki and FinancialAdvantage API to get company data.
    </p>

    <p class = "myDesc fade">
      In Train Baron, players strategize their train routes to maximize their winnings from delivering goods on time. Designing game mechanics and pixel art was challenging and rewarding. This game makes heavy use of coroutines to track user progress toward their goals. 
    </p>

    <p class = "myDesc fade">
      This duck platformer features mama duck navigating the treacherous streets of New York while keeping her ducklings safe. In this game, I improved my pixel art skills with several graphics such as exploding ducklings, lunging dogs and annoyed pedestrians. 
    </p>            
  </div>

  <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
  <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>

  <div class="slideImg">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <%= image_tag "games/zombie.png", :class=>"slide_image"%>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <%= image_tag "games/investing.png", :class=>"slide_image" %>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <%= image_tag "games/train.png", :class=>"slide_image" %>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <%= image_tag "games/duck.png", :class=>"slide_image" %>
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next">&#10095;</a>

  </div>

</div>

<br>


<h3>Artificial Intelligence</h3>
<div class="projectname">
<%= image_tag "ai.png", :class=>"icon_image"%>

<div class="slideContainer">

  <div class="slideDesc">
    <p class = "myDesc fade">
      Farm Wars: Zombie Survival is a RPG as a duck farmer who must survive in a zombie-infested desert with a handful of tools and weapons. This Unity game is compatible with Android phones.
    </p>

    <p class = "myDesc fade">
      I built this stock market educational game to encourage users to adopt a wiser approach toward investing. I scraped info of public companies to quiz users who could use their earnings to build their portfolio. I used Sqlite3 to store user progress and MediaWiki and FinancialAdvantage API to get company data.
    </p>

    <p class = "myDesc fade">
      In Train Baron, players strategize their train routes to maximize their winnings from delivering goods on time. Designing game mechanics and pixel art was challenging and rewarding. This game makes heavy use of coroutines to track user progress toward their goals. 
    </p>

  </div>

  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>

  <div class="slideImg">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <%= image_tag "ai/asteroid.png", :class=>"slide_image"%>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <%= image_tag "ai/mars.png", :class=>"slide_image" %>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <%= image_tag "ai/warehouse.png", :class=>"slide_image" %>
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next">&#10095;</a>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: when the handler is called, `newSlideshow` will be the last one you created for all the event handlers - try `let newSlideshow = new slideshow();`

Comment: Thank you. It works now. So i'm guessing `addEventListener` does not execute immediately, and as a result used the last declaration of `newSlideshow`

Comment: you guessed wrong. `addEventListener` **does** execute immediately - but the event that triggers the handler does not

Comment: ok thanks. i learned the difference between global variables and function scope today in Js.